# What's the most reliable way to distinguish local from remote logins in .bashrc?

Tags: login, remote, bashrc

What's the most reliable way to distinguish local from remote logins in .bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `env` command time. I find that when I ssh into a remote host that a variable called `$SSH_CLIENT` is set and it's value is the IP address from which I am connecting.

You could check to see if that variable is null or not.

```
if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
    // code when local login
else
    // code when remote login
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ssh` (as you really should :) you can look for environment variables starting with `$SSH_`.  Another way is `who -u am i`, which will show a hostname for remote logins.